# Got an error while installing game through airtest python

Tags: python, android, automation

I got the following error while trying to install the apk file using airtest python

```
Failure to initialize 

your hardware doesnot support this application 

failed to load 'libmain.so'

java.lang..unsatisfiedLinkerror: dlopen failed: library "libmain.so" not found

press ok to quit

this is the code i have written and i want the apk file to be installed

init_device("Android")
install("C:/GoldFish/base.apk")
apk_path="C:\\Users\\Rakesh_P\\Desktop\\Gold\\com.williamsinteractive.goldfish.apk"

install(apk_path)
start_app("com.williamsinteractive.goldfish")
sleep(20.0)
```